# NSCursor images on a retina display

Tags: cocoa, image-processing, cursor, nsimage

I am trying to modify the default I-beam cursor image. I'm using `[[[NSCursor IBeamCursor] image] representations]`, passing each one through a CIFilter and adding it to a new image. However, **the resulting cursor looks as though it is rendering the low-resolution images.**

The [High Resolution Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html) say:

> For custom cursors, you can pass a multirepresentation TIFF to the NSCursor class method `initWithImage:hotSpot:`.

So I would expect this to work. Additionally, if I get the `-TIFFRepresentation` of the original image and my modified image, and write them to disk, they both look like multi-page TIFF files with the same size images. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a somewhat-temporary solution: manually call `-setSize:` on each image representation, dividing the pixel height and width by the screen's scale factor. However, this technique doesn't seem like it will work ideally with multiple screens.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, no any good solution for retina cursors yet?

Answer (score 2):

You're right on. I've been debugging this all day and I'm pretty sure I've got it nailed. I'm not doing exactly the same thing you are (my images are loaded from a file) but the end result is exactly the same.

The trick is to set the first representation of the multi-representation image to the non-retina size. If you are loading your cursors from an image file, you must take this extra step to adjust the size of the representations to match. It doesn't work 'out-of-the-box' as you would expect.

I've tested this on a machine with two monitors and dragging the window from the retina display to the non-retina display acts as it should, displaying the high/low resolution images for the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem a while ago: I had my cursor in a PDF, and it always drew as if it was a pixel image at 1:1 size, blown up. There's a solution to that in [NSCursor: Using high-resolution cursors with cursor zoom (or retina)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245387/nscursor-using-high-resolution-cursors-with-cursor-zoom-or-retina/28246196#28246196).

Maybe someone can use that technique to solve this problem? My guess is creating an image with the same size but a different CTM marks it as the same size but Retina. What @jtbrandes is doing probably marks it as a different size and non-Retina. So you're effectively losing the scale factor information. If you create an image with a CTM in the hints, maybe you can draw the filtered images into it and it'll be detected right.

Comment: CTM is the Context Transformation Matrix. It's a Quartz/CoreGraphics (and Cocoa drawing, by extension, see NSAffineTransform etc.) thing that defines how coordinates get mapped to pixels. "marks" is supposed to be the verb here. Sorry if I was being cryptic.